# Chrome os screenshot

Tags: screenshot, google-chrome-os

I am new to chrome OS -

I want to understand if there is a way to take a screenshot of entire desktop or particular app in CHROME BOOk through command line? Or any app that can take screenshots that can be scheduled to take screenshots at regular interval. Does chrome OS take remote cmd line executions?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a screenshot by pressing

[Ctrl+F5](http://d0od.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/screenshot.jpg)

Or you can just make a screenshot from a particular area by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F5

For command-line you need to enable developer mode and you need a suitable binary for amd64 or ARM...

Edit: Commandline apps don't have access to Chrome OS's window manager, which is needed for screenshots over it. But recently rumors popped up about running native Linux applications in Chrome OS without developer mode and crouton/dualboot.

---

**Source:http://www.omgchrome.com/take-screenshot-chromebook-chromeos/**